# Displaying an image on pyqt

Tags: python, image, pyqt

I'm trying to display an image in pyqt for my coursework. I'm attempting this in the Handle Question sub routine. here's a sample of it

```
class IntegrationQuestions(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        from equation import IntQuestion, IntAnswer
        QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setWindowTitle('Simple Integration')
        self.setMinimumSize(265,400)

        self.lbl1 = QtGui.QLabel("Integrate the equation below",self)
        self.lbl1.move(0,0)
        self.lbl1.resize(200,20)

        self.lbl2 = QtGui.QLabel(pretty(IntQuestion[0], use_unicode = False), self)
        self.lbl2.resize(200, 80)
        self.lbl2.move(30,30)

        self.lbl3 = QtGui.QLabel("Sketch pad",self)
        self.lbl3.move(0,120)

        self.SketchPad = QtGui.QLineEdit(self)
        self.SketchPad.resize(250,150)
        self.SketchPad.move(0,150)

        self.lbl4 = QtGui.QLabel("Answer",self)
        self.lbl4.move(0,300)

        self.Answer = QtGui.QLineEdit(self)
        self.Answer.move(0,330)
        self.Answer.resize(250,20)


        self.next_question.clicked.connect(self.HandleQuestion)
```

## this is where I'm attempting to add in a question

```
    def HandleQuestion(self):
        pic = QtGui.QLabel(self)
        pic.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("Q107.png"))

        self.lbl3.move(0,190)
        self.SketchPad.resize(250,80)
        self.SketchPad.move(0,220)
```

Comment: I am not familiar with PyQt, however, I think you need to add `pic.show()` after `pic.setPixmap(...)`

Comment: If that worked for you, I will ask that you accept my answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You initialized everything properly, however you never set the label to be shown.

```
def HandleQuestion(self):
    pic = QtGui.QLabel(self)
    pic.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("Q107.png"))

    pic.show() # You were missing this.

    self.lbl3.move(0,190)
    self.SketchPad.resize(250,80)
    self.SketchPad.move(0,220)
```